# Ошибка выдаёт когда запускаю бот IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

Когда запускаю бот возникает вот такая проблема

```
File "/storage/emulated/0/bot.py", line 169
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
 def bot_photo(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
        if chat_info != False:
            bot.send_photo(chat_info[1], message.photo.file_id)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Шумо ҳоло чатро сар накардед!')
```

Comment: Отступы кривые. В том коде что вы привели у `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])`, у следующей строки отступ один пробел, этого пробела не должно быть. Строки должны быть с одним и тем же отступом, если не меняется вложенность кода.

Comment: @insolor Я еже написал это в ответе, кажется чуть-чуть быстрее вас :)

Comment: @nchistov нет смысла на любую мелкую проблему давать ответ.

Comment: @insolor но тем более нет смысла писать в комментарии тоже что и в ответе.

Comment: @nchistov не имело смысл писать ответ, вопросы вызванные опечатками нужно закрывать.

Comment: @insolor Бро можете написат мне в тг пожалуйста мой ник mnichh2

Comment: Не могу, я не занимаюсь ментроством.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы уберите пробел перед `def bot_photo...`.

То есть так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def bot_photo(message):
^
| -- здесь
```